# How to make partitions using gparted?

Tags: gparted, partitioning

Resize move options are disabled, so how are you make partitions using gparted?

[image]

Comment: is that image existed ?

Comment: here... https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/sphotos-e.ak/hphotos-ak-ash3/p480x480/555074_232027026951610_1154597209_n.png

Answer (score 0):

Its looking like you have installed Ubuntu in  total part of the disk. So that partition was mounted because your Ubuntu functioning through that partition.

**what you have to do ?**

You can not edit that partition unless you unmount it & you can not run your system with out mounting it.

**Solution:** Make either bootable DVD or USB of Ubuntu and then choose try Ubuntu for the live system. then open Gparted in the live system and do the same process for editing disk partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you **dont have Ubuntu ISO** right now , dont worry. we have one more way for you.

Download gparted ISO from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/

Then make it as bootable USB/CD from unetbootin tool or ISO burner. Then set your BIOS to boot from Live Gparted and when booted choose the option as `Gparted Live (default options)` and then you will get a CLI screen there type as `startx`

thats it , you will get Live Gparted opened & you are ready for partition.