# Recover unlocated USB drive

Tags: 16.04, usb, mount

I was going to format my USB drive. But unfortunately, I deleted the partition. Now my PC is not able to detect the USB anymore. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: What partition manager is failing to see the USB drive?  Or is it just failing to auto-mount when you insert it (to be expected, since there's no volume on the device to mount)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Gparted installed? There you should be able to see your USB and create a new partition for it.

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install gparted
```

Comment: @ZeissIkon I don't know about Kubuntu but in standard Ubuntu GParted isn't installed by default. It's in the live session but isn't installed.

Comment: yes.I have alrady installed it

Comment: @CelticWarrior Thanks for the correction -- I've never installed any flavor other than Kubuntu, so wouldn't have known that.

Comment: @tanvirhossain do you see your usb in the gparted menu? Drop down in the top right corner.                      e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/343802/how-to-make-partitions-using-gparted